# SQL Server Stored Procedure to loop through comma seperated list

Tags: sql-server, stored-procedures

Is it possible to create a stored procedure that will split a comma separated list and then loop through the list and perform update statements?

This is just 3 updates of what runs into several hundred update statements that is in the region of 120,000 chars long, that are executed concurrently:

```
UPDATE OPERATION 
SET START = '20151012', FINISH = '20151012' 
WHERE REF = '912^0^15'; 

UPDATE OPERATION 
SET START = '20151012', FINISH = '20151013' 
WHERE REF = '913^0^15'; 

UPDATE OPERATION 
SET START = '20151013', FINISH = '20151014' 
WHERE REF = '872^0^15';
```

What I am thinking is instead, passing a list to a procedure and then have it create the update statements, thereby reducing the length of each update from 111 chars per record to around 30 chars.

I don't know how to write stored procedures in SQL Server, but in javascript I would do it something like this:

Pseudo code:

```
list = "'20151012','20151012','912^0^15'|'20151012', '20151013','913^0^15'|'20151013','20151014','872^0^15'"

for each list.split('|') as row
    cols = row.split(',')

    UPDATE OPERATION  
    SET START = 'cols[0]', FINISH = 'cols[1]' 
    WHERE REF = 'cols[2]';
```

Is it possible to create a stored procedure that can do this?

Comment: Did you even try? There are many ways to split data starting from split function or using XML and cross apply

Comment: Why do you care how many characters are in the `update` statement?

Comment: There are around 120,000 chars in the update statements, I would like to reduce this.

Comment: could you insert this data in a temporal table (start, finish, ref) and then run one update?

Answer (score 0):

I don't like your idea at all. But to prove that it is possible I've prepared small demo:

**[LiveDemo](https://data.stackexchange.com/stackoverflow/query/373963#messages)**

```
DECLARE @string NVARCHAR(MAX) = 
 '20151012,20151012,912^0^15|20151012, 20151013,913^0^15|20151013,20151014,872^0^15';

CREATE TABLE #OPERATION(START NVARCHAR(100), FINISH NVARCHAR(100), REF NVARCHAR(100));

INSERT INTO #OPERATION 
VALUES ('', '', '912^0^15'),
       ('', '', '913^0^15'),
       ('', '', '872^0^15');


WITH cte AS
(
SELECT  
xml_data = CAST(REPLACE(REPLACE('<d>'+REPLACE(REPLACE(@string,'|','</d><d>'), ',' ,'</e><e>') +'</d>', '</d>', '</e></d>'), '<d>', '<d><e>') AS XML)
) , cte2 AS (
SELECT record.r.value('e[1]', 'NVARCHAR(100)') AS [start],
       record.r.value('e[2]', 'NVARCHAR(100)') AS [finish],
       record.r.value('e[3]', 'NVARCHAR(100)') AS [ref]
FROM cte
CROSS APPLY xml_data.nodes('//d') AS record(r)
)
UPDATE o
SET Start  = c.[start]
   ,finish = c.[finish]
FROM #OPERATION o
JOIN cte2 c
  ON c.ref = o.ref;

SELECT *
FROM #Operation;
```

You can wrap it with stored procedure where `@string` is parameter.

**[StoredProcedureDemo](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!6/20b1b/1/1)**

```
CREATE PROCEDURE dbo.my_custom_update
  @string NVARCHAR(MAX)
AS
BEGIN
SET NOCOUNT ON;

WITH cte AS
(
SELECT  
xml_data = CAST(REPLACE(REPLACE('<d>'+REPLACE(REPLACE(@string,'|','</d><d>'), ',' ,'</e><e>') +'</d>', '</d>', '</e></d>'), '<d>', '<d><e>') AS XML)
) , cte2 AS (
SELECT record.r.value('e[1]', 'NVARCHAR(100)') AS [start],
       record.r.value('e[2]', 'NVARCHAR(100)') AS [finish],
       record.r.value('e[3]', 'NVARCHAR(100)') AS [ref]
FROM cte
CROSS APPLY xml_data.nodes('//d') AS record(r)
)
UPDATE o
SET Start  = c.[start]
   ,finish = c.[finish]
FROM OPERATION o
JOIN cte2 c
  ON c.ref = o.ref;

END;
GO
```

Comment: Thanks so much for helping, but why don't you like the idea ? - this statement is around 120,000 chars long at the moment, and it is likely that this will increase to be over 250,000 chars, depending upon the number of records.

Comment: @crankshaft It depends. In my opinion sending comma separated string, then parsing it will take more time than sending multiple update calls. You could try with inserts per 1000 record per batch with `INSERT INTO ... VALUES(...), ... x ... (....)`. Anyway I may be wrong and in your case proposed solution will help.

Answer (score 0):

Try using XML like this

```
DECLARE     @list VARCHAR(MAX) = '''20151012'',''20151012'',''912^0^15''|''20151012'', ''20151013'',''913^0^15''|''20151013'',''20151014'',''872^0^15'''

SELECT      s.rowno
            , MAX(CASE WHEN s.colno = 1 THEN s.value END) AS start
            , MAX(CASE WHEN s.colno = 2 THEN s.value END) AS finish
            , MAX(CASE WHEN s.colno = 3 THEN s.value END) AS ref
FROM        (
            SELECT      c.rowno
                        , ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY c.rowno ORDER BY (SELECT 1))
                        , REPLACE(LTRIM(d.x.value('(./text())[1]', 'VARCHAR(MAX)')), '''', '')
            FROM        (
                        SELECT      ROW_NUMBER() OVER (ORDER BY (SELECT 1))
                                    , CONVERT(XML, '<i>' + REPLACE(b.x.value('(./text())[1]', 'VARCHAR(MAX)'), ',', '</i><i>') + '</i>')
                        FROM        ( 
                                    SELECT      CONVERT(XML, '<i>' + REPLACE(@list, '|', '</i><i>') + '</i>')
                                    ) a(x)
                        CROSS APPLY a.x.nodes('i') b(x)
                        ) c(rowno, x)
            CROSS APPLY c.x.nodes('i') d(x)
            ) s(rowno, colno, value)
GROUP BY    s.rowno
```